# Remove WPF GridView Item margin

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

How do I remove the GridView item margin that is added in WPF?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It called `RowHeaderWidth` not Item's margin. So, what you have to do it just set `RowHeaderWidth="0"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally found it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use remove properties to remove the selected item from the Gridview.
For example:

```
if(datagrid.SelectedIndex >= 0) 
{ 
  Student student = datagrid.SelectedItem as Student; 
  col.Remove(student); 
}
```